When did the term "mental gymnastics" start being used in a negative context?
I remember using the term "mental gymnastics" during message board arguments in the early 2000's. I'm curious if it changed it's meaning around that time.
I do not think I originated negative use of the term but I know that's where I picked up on it. I had to explain what I meant to people who hadn't heard it used in that way before.
I'm just curious.

Please clarify the question. Are you talking about the sense here?

My intuition makes me think the meaning you have in mind is justifying your wrong actions with clever excuses. But you should make that clear in your OP.

It's in Wiktionary, Farlex, and BBC Learning English, with both senses (positive and negative).

This could be a good question if you explained the meaning you are interested in and ideally gave one or more examples. Many sources give definitions so it should be possible to find something.

When referring to negative use of the expression, do you mean assuming a conclusion while dismissing evidence to the contrary ?

Potential answer if reopened: The term mental gymnastics refers to an explanation or argument that involves convoluted or complex thought that is motivated or special pleading in order to win the argument. It is often used as a euphemism for poor or erroneous thinking, giving the benefit of the doubt that the explainer is at least trying hard. It is often in contrast to a much simpler explanation that doesn't need any special manipulation of words to make the case. It has not changed its meaning in the past 25 years.

By ascribing the thinking to gymnastics, the speaker is already using a slur. Aerobic exercise by definition counters Occam's razor: the elegance of simplicity.

The phrase was being used pejoratively even in the late 1940s and early 1950s to refer to dishonest or specious arguments, sophistry, pretzel logic, casuistry, and such.  Just search Google Books for "resort to mental gymnastics" and you'll find attestations of the pejorative use post WWII.

Can you first say why you believe the term 'mental gymnastics' has ever had a negative context?
More than in most cases, this seems to show how 'Context is king…' since neither Question title nor exposition provides any context…

The term 'mental gymnastics' refers to an explanation or argument that involves convoluted or complex thought that is motivated or uses special pleading in order to win the argument, metaphorically using complex maneuvers to land on ones argumentative feet.
It is usually used as a euphemism for poor or erroneous thinking, or explanations for untenable claims using more and more elaborate justification for unlikely argument points. It is often in contrast to a much simpler explanation that doesn't need any special manipulation of words to make the case.
It has always bee used in a negative way even though it sounds like it is describing skillful use of thought. It has not changed its meaning in the past 25 years. A Google NGrams search shows that it has been used in the sense we use now since ~1860, with no clear originating source.

But Wiktionary lists this other use of term as well: Difficult and complex logical thought processes, especially when performed effortlessly. So you might say Kant was skilled in mental gymnastics without being pejorative.

My impression is that the term reflects not so much on the quality of the arguments that are characterised by it, as the motivation for making them: it usually suggests that the person making the arguments is more interested in the process of argumentation than its subject matter. An argument that is, as a matter of logic, perfectly OK, may thus be said to involve mental gymnastics, if it is excessively elaborate for the matter under discussion.
